# How do you enforce Layout Constraints when defining syntax for languages like Python or YAML in Rascal?

Tags: yaml, rascal

Considering the following snippet, how do I define layout(indentation and alignment) constraints to disambiguate the mappings to the ": " operator as in the [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#21-collections)

```
start syntax Empty = ;
start syntax Document = Block+;

syntax Block = MappingBlock;

syntax MappingBlock = Id ":
  " Value+;

syntax Value 
            = SequenceValue
            | QuotedValue
            | PlainValue
            | Number
            ;

syntax SequenceValue = "- " Value;

syntax QuotedValue = String;

syntax PlainValue = Id;

syntax Number = Integer;
```

When I try to parse this with a single value like this sample:

```
name:
  - "test"
```

It works but when I try

```
name:
  - "test"
  - "testing"
```

I get a parse error.

```
rascal>parse(#Document, yml);
Reloading module YamlDemo
|TODO:///|: ParseError(|project://rascal-test-project/src/resources/test.yml|(16,1,<2,10>,<2,11>))
ok
```

Comment: There is a YAML parser in the standard library as well. We used a commonly used open-source version which maps to Rascal's ADTs. See `lang::yaml::Model`

Answer (score 2):

Rascal has only context-free grammars with disambiguation declarations which are (mostly) context-free. None of the existing built-in disambiguation mechanisms, even if they add context information, are specifically apt at solving layout constraints. So priority (`>`) and associativity (`left`, `right`), keyword reservation `\` and the follow and precede restrictions (!>>, !<<, >>, <<) are out of scope.

We have been working on generalizing Rascal's grammars to data-dependent context-free grammars, which can naturally express layout constraints. See this paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2814228.2814242 However, that work is not integrated into Rascal yet.

Not to worry, there is a solution:

1. Write an ambiguous grammar for the language, one which accepts all the correct strings and nothing more, but does not know how to choose between trees that are only different because of how they are indented.
2. Write filter functions that remove layout-rule-offending trees from the forest using the `filter` statement.
3. Pass the filter functions directly into the `parse` function, such that they can be used efficiently when the parse graph is collapsed to a parse forest.

From the [ParseTree](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Library/ParseTree/) module:

> `&T<:Tree parse(type[&T<:Tree] begin, str input, bool allowAmbiguity=false, bool hasSideEffects=false, set[Tree(Tree)] filters={})`

When building the tree after parsing the parser function will try to apply all filter functions to every node.

- When the function parameters do not match, then the filter does nothing. * When it does match, then the filter function is applied and the returned tree replaces the parse tree that went in.
- When the function uses `filter`, the current tree is removed from the ambiguity cluster that containt it. That might be somewhat higher up in the tree, so you can filter smaller sub-trees without having to care about arbitrary context.

An example filter function:

```
Exp filterOffside(Exp e) {
   int column = e@\loc.begin.column;

   if (/Exp child := e, e@\loc.begin.column < column) {
     filter; // offside! so cut it out
   }
}
```

Which you would pass by name to the `parse` function:

```
parse(#Exp, someInput, allowAmbiguity=true, filters={filterOffside})
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll try this out but could you explain the example filterOffside function in a bit more detail, I don't understand the /Exp and e@\loc.begin.column, how do I interpret these syntax?

Comment: Hi Wayne; in a filter function you can write any rascal code. The := means pattern matching with the pattern left and the subject right. The / pattern is "deep" match. So basically this part means find all Exp subtrees and bind them to `child` one-by-one. If one of them start to the right of the limit, bang! We're offside.

Comment: So I tried this out but I keep getting an error. 
No definition found for keyword field or anno `\loc` in type `Exp`. Do you know how I could rectify that?

Comment: I tried some stuff and started getting a new error 
`Expected set[Tree (Tree)], but got set[Exp (Exp)]`. Do you have an idea what could be the cause and how to fix?

Comment: That is also unexpected to me. `set[Exp(Exp)]` should be a proper sub-type of `set[Tree(Tree)]` imo. I'll have a look. Yes indeed, something like this works: `set[Tree(Tree)] filters = {f};` where f is `Exp f(Exp e) = e;`. So you could use this intermediate variable to work around the bug.

Comment: Could you send us the code that triggered this issue in a [github](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues) issue? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: I stopped getting an error when I restarted my vscode, I guess the compiler hadn't resolved all the changes when I was developing. But the filter doesn't seem to reach what I'm targeting. 
Take this snippet for example `if (/(Exp)``<Id _> : <DLM? _> <{Block DLM}+ blockList>`` := e, e@\loc.begin.column < column) {
    filter;
  } else {
    return e;
  }`

I'm trying to target the `blockList` but when I use it, I can't implode the resulting tree.

Comment: When I also try to check the resulting tree, it's still ambiguous. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Typically there are more ambiguities to solve in the same file. I use the `firstAmbiguity` function for that. It's very fast. That way you can solve one ambiguity at a time. Next, I use `vis::Text::prettyTree` to get a quick textual overview of the ambiguity. It helps to `println` just before your `filter`, to make sure at least something happens :-)